# How to switch between two websites in a domain name?

Tags: 16.04, server

I have a server running Ubuntu 16.04. When you type the domain name, for example, www.mydomainname.com it leads you to a board1. And when you type an ip address like 189.11.22.1:40443 (or domain name with the port) it leads you to another, board2.

I want to switch between these two boards: put the first board1 on ip address and the second one on the domain name.

How can I do that?

P.s. I am using nginx for configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With apache2 `<virtualhost>` directive, you can set servername, that corresponds to the domain name. So you point 2 names to same ip, and serve those from 2 virtualhosts, that are placed in different directories.

You can also specify ports to listen on virtualhost directive.

For example:

```
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pasiz.net
    ServerAlias www.pasiz.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.pasiz.net/htdocs
    ServerAdmin pasiz@pasiz.net
    ErrorLog /var/www/www.pasiz.net/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www.pasiz.net/log/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

"Virtualhost" alias Server Block for nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/